# Available Shipping Methods Returns Null

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, shipping

I have created a shipping method in the CP but when I output `cart.availableShippingMethods` a null value is returned. I've checked my database and the shipping method is there.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Does your shipping method have any conditions set? Like a country or region? I think `getAvailableShippingMethods()` takes into account your shipping address (if any) and only shows shipping methods that apply to the current shipping details.

Second thing to check: does your shipping method have at least one shipping rule? Commerce needs a shipping rule to be checked against your order.

Comment: I thought that might be the case so I deleted everything and started again. I just have one Shipping Method setup with no rules or zones and I'm using the general category. Thanks for your help

Comment: Stupid question: does your shipping method have shipping rules? A shipping rules has to match the order for the shipping method to be available. Look at https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/master/src/models/ShippingRule.php#L213-L295 to see how the matching is done, it might help you figure out what's wrong?

Comment: I added a rule just to see and it now works. Seems that the method requires at least one rule. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Yes, the method always requires at least one shipping rule to be matched to your order! I will add that to my answer, for future reference :)